# walker menu, get parent element in a dropdown and child element in another element

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wp-nav-walker

here is my situation, I'm trying to have a custom wordpress menu:

- all parent element to display in a select dropdown
- all chidren element to display in another select dropdown.

so far my walker is like this:

```
  class My_Walker_Nav_Menu_language extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    $url = '#' !== $item->url ? $item->url : '';
    $output .= '<option value="' . $url . '">' . $item->title;
}   
function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth){
    $output .= "</option>\n$indent"; // replace closing </li> with the option tag
}

}
```

The problem being, it's adding parent and children element in the same select dropdown instead of two separates one . .

how can this be achieve ?

It will be super to have some help with that,

Thanks

-- EDIT --

Example:

If i have a menu like:

```
<ul id="menu-network-menu" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-537" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children YO menu-item-537">
    <a href="#">Europe</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-538" class="blog-id-4 mlp-language-nav-item menu-item menu-item-type-language menu-item-object-mlp_language menu-item-538">
            <a rel="alternate" href="http://mysite.local/fr/?noredirect=fr_FR">
                 French FR</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-542" class="blog-id-1 mlp-language-nav-item menu-item menu-item-type-language menu-item-object-mlp_language mlp-current-language-item menu-item-542">
            <a rel="alternate" href="http://mysite.local/">
                English (UK)</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-541" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children YO menu-item-541">
    <a href="#">America</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-539" class="blog-id-5 mlp-language-nav-item menu-item menu-item-type-language menu-item-object-mlp_language menu-item-539">
            <a rel="alternate" href="http://mysite.local/cr/?noredirect=es_CO">
                 CR</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-540" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children YO menu-item-540">
    <a href="http://Asia">Asia</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-543" class="blog-id-6 mlp-language-nav-item menu-item menu-item-type-language menu-item-object-mlp_language menu-item-543">
            <a rel="alternate" href="http://cn.mysite.local/?noredirect=zh">
                 China</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

To

```
<select>
<option>EUROPE</option
<option>AMERICA</option
<option>ASIA</option
</select>

<select>
<option>French FR</option
<option>English (UK)</option
<option> CR</option
<option>China</option
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i understand you want to change all menu to select dropdown if i understand correctly you question then here is working function :

```
class My_Walker_Nav_Menu_language  extends Walker_Nav_menu {


public  function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ){ //li a span
$url = '#' !== $item->url ? $item->url : '';

if ($item->menu_item_parent == 0){ 
$output .= '<select><option value="' . $url . '">' . $item->title;
}
$output .= ' <option value="' . $url . '">' . $item->title;

}
function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = Array()){ // closing li a span
if ($item->menu_item_parent == 0){ 
$output .= "</option></select> "; // replace closing </li> with the option tag
}
$output .= "</option>"; // replace closing </li> with the option tag
}

}
```

Comment: Hi Kashalo,

thanks for this, what im looking to have is almos tthis.

Currently with your code it create a select dropdown for each parent item.

I'd liek to have only two select dropdown.

the first select dropdown will contain only the parent item of the menu.

The second select dropdown will contain only the children items.

Let me know if tat make sense ?

I will update my question with the html to help.

Thanks a lot it's already better than what I had !

Comment: yes please update your question with some basic html example which you are looking to rewrite the code

Comment: any thought @kashalo ?